# How do i use a lockscreen from another rom

Tags: lock-screens, custom-roms, rom, customization

I want to use only the lock screen from another rom for the same phone.
I own Micromax A52.

And I am using Xzoom v3 as my rom with Dark Angel theme.(to be precise if anyone knows and if it matters :P)

But i want to use the lock screen from another rom 'SuperStock52' which is also a rom for the same device.

How can i port that lock screen to my rom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the lock screen is some kind of 3rd party app (like [GO Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5qaXViYW5nLmdvc2NyZWVubG9jayJd)), then I believe you would have to modify the ROM yourself, and port the lock screen over manually, into your 'new' ROM. - In which case you might be better off asking for advice over at [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/), or another developer forum.

If it is some kind of 3rd party app, chances are you can download & install it from the Play store, or download the APK online from the developer's website.

**EDIT:** Rereading your question it's occured to me you might actually be asking *how* to port over the lock screen (IE: which files to modify in the ROM) - in which case, you should probably go to XDA (see above link) and ask for advice.